# m_line boundary for stereographic map

Tags: matlab, dictionary, plot

[image]Using M_map package for Matlab, I have created a stereographic projection map of the Arctic. I went on further to create boundary to specify a certain area. Unfortunately, using m_line gives me a straight line from point to point when it should be a curved line. how do I fix this?

```
figure()
m_proj('stereographic','lat',90,'rad',22,'lon',0)
m_coast('patch',[.5 .5 .5],'edgecolor',[0 0 0]); hold 
m_grid ('box', 'fancy', 'ytick',(70:5:90));
[cs,h]=m_tbase('contour',[-250 -1000 -2000 -3000], 'edgecolor', 'k', 'linewidt', 0.00001);
[LongitudeProj, LatitudeProj]=m_ll2xy(longitude, latitude);

bndry_lon=[0 125 125 0 0 ];
bndry_lat=[86    86  90  90  86 ];
m_line(bndry_lon,bndry_lat,'linewi',2,'color','g');
```

The green line in the image attached is how the code draws the m_line... but the brown line is how it should be drawn since it is a stereographic projection.

Comment: Without looking at the details: Would it be an option to just use multiple points for the plot? (Of course you would have to calculate their locations manually in advance)

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you mean? the first part of the code just plots the map and it is just for reference. the second part of the code where it is bndry_lon and lat is where i specify the 4 corners of the polygon.. on a normal map, it would plot a rectangle given those 4 points.. it looks like a triangle now only because 90N 125E and 90N 0E are actually very close together, otherwise it is still a 4-sided polygon(green). however, since it is stereographic, the bottom part should follow 86N latitude (like the brown line) and not a straight line cutting across other latitudes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the function is just made to find points on a map, and connect them with a straight line (As you currently see happening).

A way to get what you want might be to work around this with a polygon that consists of many points, for example:

```
bndry_lon=[linspace(0,125,100) 125 0 0 ];
bndry_lat=[linspace(86,86,100)  90  90  86 ];
```

If you believe the function is capable of producing the curved line that you seek directly, please find/create a simple example so we can pick it up from there.

Comment: Yes, I think it does the job. Another example, where it is easier to see it is bndry_lon_NAN=[0 125 125 0 0 ]; bndry_lat_NAN=[82 82 86 86 82 ]; so if I use bndry_lon_NAN=[linspace(0,125,100) linspace(125,0,100) 0 ]; bndry_lat_NAN=[linspace(82,82,100) linspace(86,86,100) 82 ];   then you can see the top and bottom curves accurately. Could you explain what linspace and adding 100 at the end does? Thank you!

Comment: @Bala Just check `doc linspace` basically I just interpolate linearly between the points in 100 steps.